# Get Lagging and Leading Values Within Set Time Period For Each ID/Key In Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Is there a way to get a lagging and leading value from a pandas dateframe that is date constrained in both the lagging and leading direction and can be calculated relative to a specific column(s), similar to a group-by?

Example:
I have a dataframe of user ids, event ids and their dates. A second dateframe has been left joined onto it that contains measurements for that user that occur around the date of the original event date.

For each event (event id), I would like to get the measurement value nearest to (but not exceeding) 2 months *before* the event date and 6 months *after* (not exceeding)

**Starting Dataframe Example**

| User ID | Event ID | Event Date | Measure Date | Measure Value | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1111 | 6-1-2022 | 2-1-2022 | 5 |  |
| X | 1111 | 6-1-2022 | 3-15-2022 | 6 |  |
| X | 1111 | 6-1-2022 | 4-15-2022 | 7 | (date nearest to 2 month before) |
| X | 1111 | 6-1-2022 | 5-15-2022 | 8 |  |
| X | 1111 | 6-1-2022 | 8-15-2022 | 8 |  |
| X | 1111 | 6-1-2022 | 12-1-2022 | 10 | (Date nearest 6 mo after event) |
| X | 1111 | 6-1-2022 | 12-08-2022 | 15 |  |
| Y | 2222 | 3-1-2022 | 1-1-2022 | 33 | (date nearest to 2 month before) |
| Y | 2222 | 3-1-2022 | 5-15-2022 | 8 |  |
| Y | 2222 | 3-1-2022 | 6-15-2022 | 67 | (Date nearest 6 mo after event) |
| Y | 2222 | 3-1-2022 | 12-08-2022 | 15 |  |

**Desired output:**

| User ID | Event ID | Event Date | 2 mo prior date | 2 mo value | 6 mo after date | 6 mo value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1111 | 6-1-2022 | 4-15-2022 | 7 | 12-1-2022 | 10 |
| Y | 2222 | 3-1-2022 | 1-1-2022 | 33 | 6-15-2022 | 67 |

I have tried grouping by User ID, Event ID, and Event Date and using pandas shift(), however because the measurements are not exactly X number of rows before or after the initial event, this doesn't work. Shift is also not date constrained.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer these frames unmerged. You can then use numpy broadcasting to compare every row in `events` against every row in `measures` to look for matches and filter them. Note that the solution will require `len(events) * len(measures) * 8` bytes of memory. If your dataframes are really long, you may want to compare them in chunks.

Assuming the original dataframes (before merging) look like this;

```py
events = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "User ID": ["X", "Y"],
        "Event ID": [1111, 2222],
        "Event Date": ["2022-06-01", "2022-03-01"],
    }
)

measures = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Event ID": [1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 2222, 2222, 2222, 2222],
        "Measure Date": [
            "2022-02-01",
            "2022-03-15",
            "2022-04-15",
            "2022-05-15",
            "2022-08-15",
            "2022-12-01",
            "2022-12-08",
            "2022-01-01",
            "2022-05-15",
            "2022-06-15",
            "2022-12-08",
        ],
        "Measure Value": [5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10, 15, 33, 8, 67, 15],
    }
)
```

Solution:

```py
# Always convert datetime to proper dtype
events["Event Date"] = pd.to_datetime(events["Event Date"])
measures["Measure Date"] = pd.to_datetime(measures["Measure Date"])

# Sorting the `measures` frame is critical to the algorithm
measures = measures.sort_values("Measure Date")

# Convert the relavent columns into numpy arrays to prepare for broadcasting.
# All columns from `events` are raised up one dimension with [:, None]
event_id = events["Event ID"].to_numpy()[:, None]
start_date = (events["Event Date"] - pd.DateOffset(months=2)).to_numpy()[:, None]
end_date = (events["Event Date"] + pd.DateOffset(months=6)).to_numpy()[:, None]

# The columns from `measures` are just straight-exported to numpy. Nothing
# special here.
measure_event_id = measures["Event ID"].to_numpy()
measure_date = measures["Measure Date"].to_numpy()
measure_value = measures["Measure Value"].to_numpy()

# Compare every row in `events` against every row in `measures`. Two rows are matched if
#   - They have the same Event ID
#   - The Measure Date is between start_date and end_date
is_match = (
    (event_id == measure_event_id)
    & (start_date <= measure_date)
    & (measure_date <= end_date)
)

# For each row, get the index of the first cell that has the value 1.
first_match = np.argmax(is_match, axis=1)

# For each row, get the index of the last cell that has the value 1.
# Since np.argmax returns the *first* index, we need to reverse each row then do
# some index manipulations to get the last index.
last_match = len(measures) - np.argmax(is_match[:, ::-1], axis=1) - 1

# The result
result = events.assign(
    **{
        "2 mo prior date": measure_date[first_match],
        "2 mo value": measure_value[first_match],
        "6 mo after date": measure_date[last_match],
        "6 mo value": measure_value[last_match]
    }
)
```